# Get own base address - multiple processes with the same name

Tags: c#, process, base-address

In my DLL attached to an application I would like to find its (the application's) base address, but I don't think I can use `FindProcessByName` as I will have multiple instances of this application running. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Process.GetCurrentProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess).

Comment: And how would you get the baseAddress? Because that is not a property on Process....

Comment: The base address in which address space?

Comment: That is a good question. I wonder what the OP is going to do with that info...you answer got accepted so all is good now...

Answer (score 1):

*Process.ProcessName* property holds an executable file name, such as Outlook, that does not include the .exe extension or the path. It is helpful for getting and manipulating all the processes that are associated with the same executable file.

Here is the [reference link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).